# eddy currents to heat reinforcing steel

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

The latest cook tops heat iron pans using high frequency circuits. IS it possible to do this with construction reinforcing steel also known as rebar) used in concrete slabs? I put rebar on a cook top and it did not heat up . Does the metal in construction rebar not have enough ferromagnetic properties? Do you need to put coils around the rebar in various locations to heat it up? I only want to heat it to maybe 40 degrees Celsius / 104 degree Fahrenheit.

Comment: Bottom of a cooking pan is a disk. I don't really know how those cooktops work, but if the eddy currents circulate around the disk... Your skinny piece of rebar might be made of the right stuff, but it might be the wrong shape.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to heat rebar with eddy currents, you should use a drive coil that envelops the bar so the bar is running down the center of the coil. this trick is commonly used to heat-treat machine parts. Only that portion of the bar in close proximity to the coil will get hot.